# c# how to save an attachment to a folder? .Net2

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

I am creating a csv file and attaching it to an email like so...

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csv)))
            {
                try
                {
                    to = "email@email.com";
                    string from = "user@email.co.uk";
                    string subject = "Order p"+ OrderNumber;
                    string body = result;
                    SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
                    MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(stream, new ContentType("text/csv"));
                    attachment.Name = "p" + OrderNo + "_" + CustomerReference+".csv";
                    mailObj.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
```

This works fine, but how to i save the same csv file to a folder?thanks

Comment: Just edited my answer, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) method in System.IO is probably the simplest way to accomplish this:

```
File.WriteAllText("<destination>", csv);
```

where `<destination>` is the path of the  file to save the CSV to. This file will be created if it doesn't exist yet, otherwise it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your stream to a location:

```
var newfile = new StreamWriter(path_filename);

foreach (var l in stream)
   newfile.WriteLine(l);
newfile.Close();
```

Edited:

Use this instead:

```
StreamWriter outputfile = new StreamWriter("c:\temp\outputfile.csv");
```

and then the foreach loop.

Edited 2 (from msdn site):

```
   // Read the first 20 bytes from the stream.
   byteArray = new byte[memStream.Length];
   count = memStream.Read(byteArray, 0, 20);

   // Read the remaining bytes, byte by byte.
   while(count < memStream.Length)
            {
                byteArray[count++] = 
                    Convert.ToByte(memStream.ReadByte());
            }

   // Decode the byte array into a char array 
   // and write it to the console.
   charArray = new char[uniEncoding.GetCharCount(
   byteArray, 0, count)];
   uniEncoding.GetDecoder().GetChars(
                byteArray, 0, count, charArray, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(charArray); //here you should send to the file as the first example i wrote instead of to writing to console.
```

Comment: for stream in here, do i use csv?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Got the code from a .net 4 project i have here. Also didnt undertand your first comment. Let me check how to do with .net 2.

Comment: have a look here. might help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: erm thats not writing to a file i think, im using a stream currently to create the file, just need to know how to save it

Comment: So all you need is like I put in the answer, create a streamwriter and writes in it from your memorystream not using the var word ofcourse. Just edited the answer.

Comment: var i've put in the answer, use the class type StreamWriter. About foreach, I'll have a look.